# Using useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const App = () => {
    function hideCharacter(){
        const randomChar = useRef(null);
        randomChar.classList.add('hide');
    }
    return (
        <> 
            <RandomChar ref={randomChar} /> // error: not defined
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={hideCharacter()}>Load another one</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

Why my ref is not defined? I need to refactor code to class?

Comment: You are violating a rule related to hooks. Hooks can only be used at the top-level inside the functional component. See: [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: const has a block level scoping, try to move it out of hideCharacter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the React Hook Rules. Hooks should be declared in the functional component at top.

In your case **you are declaring it inside a local function** and it is not available outside that.

It has to be like:

```js
const App = () => {
    const randomChar = useRef(null); // <---declare it here
    function hideCharacter(){        
        randomChar.classList.add('hide');
    }
    return (
        <> 
            <RandomChar ref={randomChar} /> // error: not defined
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={hideCharacter()}>Load another one</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level check it here @IvanKomarnytskiy